# Umbraco Invalid object name 'umbracoUser'

Tags: version-control, bitbucket, umbraco7

We are using umbraco7.7.7 cms, using bitbucket for version control and usync extension to sync all datatype/etc. All developers have  own local database.

Problem : 
When I created the project with a fresh  new installation, setup database, created doc types and etc. and another developer pulled the project (he just changed connection string in Web.Config to setup his own database) in console he is getting the following error  : Invalid object name 'umbracoUser', while the installation still  in progress.

So how the other developer  can pull the project and run it without errors? Do we need a shared database? But then what is the usync extension purpose?

Comment: Sounds like the user you try to connect to the database does not exist. Can you try to provide more information about the setup, maybe the full error message?

Comment: Ohter developer has an empty database (his own local db). And on the first run he is getting above error.  I think it's because of connection string. Umbraco sees connection string and it asumes that database should have umbraco tables